# Converting Acrobat JavaScript to Adobe ES4 Deigner JavaScript

Tags: javascript, acrobat

I have a few JavaScripts that worked well in Acrobat. I haven't been able to get them to work in Adobe ES4 LiveCycle Designer (I'm a novice).

One of the JS is to enable a tick in a checkbox when text is entered into a text field.

In LifeCycle ES4, I have entered the JavaScript in Script editor, and have 'Show: Validate*'.  Unfortunately JavaScript seems not to be working. Any help  greatly appreciated. Acrobat JavaScript I'm trying to convert to ES4 is:

```
 this.getField("checkbox 1").checkThisBox(0, (event.value!=""));
```

Kind regards

Kevin

Comment: It should say 'Dear Experts' at the top. Thanks

Comment: Could use more code of what you are doing. And please tell what you want to happen, and how it works now.

Comment: Hi Flummox - sorry late reply. I have a form with many text fields which need to be completed. There will be  a check box  linked to each text field (for tracking purposes).  This will then quickly indicate which text fields have yet to be completed. I have used this code in Acrobat and it works, however I wish to use ES4 designer, and the code needs to be compatible.  Sorry I hope this is answering what you asked me, and thank-you for your help.

Comment: PS I can add a PDF document created in Acrobat to show what i mean - many thanks

Comment: Might be better to link to images you have loaded elsewhere. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Answer (score 1):

In short, there is no way to automatically/programmatically convert Acrobat JavaScript to XFA JScript. The object models, as well as the event handling models are too far apart.

The most reliable way to do such a conversion is to know what the Acrobat JavaScript is doing, and then find a way to do the same in XFA JScript.

In other words, recreate the script.

Comment: OK excellent. Many thanks. Sorry if this is inappropriate but would you be able to help with this? and if so how much will that be? Many thanks

Comment: I feel honored upon this request, but I must admit that my expertise is with Acrobat JavaScript, and not at all with XFA JScript…

Answer (score 0):

Use the capabilities of LiveCycle.
Create the checkbox. Create the text field.  Right-click on the text field. Select Add Action.  Set the condition of when the text field is not empty, the value of the check box to be checked. Optionally you may want to also set the check box to read only.

I'm doing this for a form I'm creating where a comment is required before the item can be checked off.